# .NET Card Game - why does the view not show?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been building this card game as a web application with a Gui using .NET Core. When a blank rectangle representing a playing card is clicked by the user, I would like a card object with random values to be generated (a name, a value and a suit) and for the user to be returned to the view with those values displayed on the blank card.

At the moment I have this link in my view that calls the function to generate a random card when it is clicked. But at the moment the link redirects the user to an error page with the text "This localhost page can't be found". I just wondered why this is?

The link is here:

```
    <a asp-controller="CardController" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
```

This is the controller action that is supposed to generate the random card:

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }   
    
    public static string GetShortName(string name)
    {
        string result = name.Substring(0, 1);
    
        return result;
    }
    public static Card CreateCard()
    {
        Card[] card1 = new Card[11];
        Random rnd1 = new Random();
    
        Array suitvalues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)); // generates a random suit
        Suit randomSuit = (Suit)suitvalues.GetValue(rnd1.Next(suitvalues.Length));
    
        var i = rnd1.Next(card1.Length);
    
        var card = new Card()
        {
            Suit = randomSuit,
            Value = i,
            DisplayName = GetShortName(randomSuit.ToString())
        };
    
        return card;
    }
    public IActionResult PlayTurn()
    {
        var card = CreateCard(); // creates a random card
        TempData["CardName"] = card.DisplayName;
        TempData["CardValue"] = card.Value;
        TempData["CardSuit"] = card.Suit.ToString();
        return Redirect("Card/Create");
    }
```

This the the complete code for the view:

```
    @model SnapCardGame.Models.Card
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
    
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to the Card Page!</h1>
    
        @if (TempData.Peek("CardName") != null)
        {
            <a asp-controller="CardController" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        @TempData.Peek("CardName")
                    </li>
                    <li>@TempData.Peek("CardValue")</li>
                    <li>@TempData.Peek("CardSuit")</li>
                </ul>
            </a>
    
        }
        else
        {
            <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
                &nbsp;
            </a>
        }
    
        <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
            &nbsp;
        </a>
    </div>
```

I'd like to pass the randomly generated values to the view via Temp Data. At the moment though, I just get the resulting page:

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions, please feel free to let me know?

Thanks,

Robert Young

London, UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your link to:

```
<a asp-controller="Card" asp-action="PlayTurn" class="card">
```

The corresponding controller name should be `Card`, not `CardController`.